# pivot not working in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

My SQL query works fine when i execute it in SQL management studio but throw the error below when execute in SSIS package. Any advise?

**When click on Build Query of the syntax - it shows

> The PIVOT SQL construct or statement is not supported.
>   Case 1:

```
SELECT listid, 
               [1] 
        FROM   (SELECT listid, 
                       val, 
                       [order] 
                FROM   gmt_listsvals) P 
               PIVOT (Max (val) 
                     FOR [order] IN ([1])) AS pvt
```

Case 2:

```
SELECT comb_id, [orgunit], [time], [gender], [jobcategory], [ethnicity], [gradegroup], [regiongeo], [emplclass], operatorid,  seq_id,  sequance_name, listid 
FROM   (SELECT C.comb_id, dim_name, V.operatorid,V.seq_id, V.listid, dim_value, S.sequance_name 
        FROM   gmt_combinationsflat C 
            JOIN gmt_valuesflat V ON C.comb_id = V.comb_id 
            JOIN gmt_rangeseq S ON V.seq_id = S.seq_id 
            JOIN gmt_dimensions D ON C.dim_id = D.dim_id 
        WHERE  C.kpi_id = 9 AND C.last = 1) P 
PIVOT (Max(dim_value) FOR dim_name IN ( [ORGUNIT ], [Time ], [Gender ], [JobCategory ], [Ethnicity ], [GradeGroup ],  [RegionGeo ], [EmplClass ] ) ) AS pvtt
```

### Error

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009 Error at ..: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80040E21. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description:
>   "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available. No work was done.".

Comment: When click on Build Query of the syntax - it shows "The PIVOT SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Comment: use `MAX(CASE WHEN order = 1 THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS [1]`

Comment: @adrianm Where should the code above go to? I tried adding in the select but it is not working

Comment: @belinq, better ask new question, rather then edit already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That statement is equivalent to:

```
select listid, max(case when [order] = 1 then val end) as [1]
from gmt_listsvals
group by listid
```

Comment: Could you advise on the 2nd cases which i updated to the question above? For the first case, it is referring to the [1] and we can do a max to get the data. But the second cases are comes with varchar values...

Comment: @belinq, ask another question and I will try to help.

Comment: It is like a blackmail :) It could never end. You can check uncheck my answer 10 times, but this is incorect. Ask another question

Comment: Hi Giorgi, i tried to add your name @Giorgi Nakeuri but it never show.. that is why i uncheck to try.. Sure i will get a new one. thanks